# SVG Envelope Deformation with snap or another SVG js-library

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, snap.svg

Good Afternoon,

Can I apply Envelope Deformation at some SVG grouping set or path or text?
I'm looking a way to deform a SVG part with javascript with a group of coordinates/vectors.

Similar to that: 
http://www.neuroproductions.be/uploads/blog/examples/envelope_distort/EnvelopeDistordTest.swf

Thanks

Comment: No its not possible afaik, other than coding your perspective paths that get amended on the fly. (ie it is possible with your own code, but those libaries won't do that for you).